# rails_admin + paperclip wont upload to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, rails-admin

I'm using `rails_admin`, and I have Paperclip configured to use an S3 bucket.

When I upload however, it just uploads locally. I have scoured internet and GitHub issues and can't find how I can achieve this.

Thank you

**initializers/paperclip.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: Settings.s3.bucket_name,
    access_key_id: Settings.s3.access_key,
    secret_access_key: Settings.s3.secret_key,
    s3_region: Settings.s3.region
  }
}
```

#### EDIT

It appears it will not even upload to S3 at all with the most basic form... is there some other step I have to do? This is my form 'test'

```
  <%= form_for Gamer.new, url: root_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
    <%= form.file_field :profile %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :rank %>
    <%= form.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bahhhhh. The answer is because if you use an initializer you can't use the first example from their docs, you have to format it like this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = {
  bucket: Settings.s3.bucket_name,
  access_key_id: Settings.s3.access_key,
  secret_access_key: Settings.s3.secret_key,
  s3_region: Settings.s3.region
}
```